# Can I embed multiple content addins into a single document

Tags: office-js

We'd like to create an addin where we could provide some custom visualisation to embed within office documents (excel, word, ppt ideally), but be able to embed multiple content in each document (page / sheet / slide etc)

Does the content addin provide this functionality?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can do any modifications to the Office documents, read more about that in the [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) section.